# What is the logic of binding huge data in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have MVC project and i'm using there some kendo grids with huge data.

When I'm binding this grids, i'm using Ajax Binding with DataSourceResult, 
I have huge data so it's binding so slow

I want to understand what is the logic of that when binding data? 
Is it fetching all data and seperate in pages inside or Is it fetching page by page?

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination when fetching the data, it is a bad idea to load everything and paginate later, you need to fetch from db page by page, this is the best practice.

Comment: I think you are right but i asked what is kendo doing ? Are they fetch everything? or is it depens on us

Comment: Use this as ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478257/kendo-ui-grid-pagination-server-side

Comment: Another useful ref:http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-server-side-paging-with-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer to a similar question posted before as reference

[How to implement Server side paging in Client side Kendo UI grid in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928744/how-to-implement-server-side-paging-in-client-side-kendo-ui-grid-in-asp-net-mvc)